# Upper bound on expectation $\mathbb{E}[Y] \leq a + \int_a^\infty \mathbb{P}(Y \geq t)dt$

Tags: expected-value, upper-lower-bounds

I found this inequality in a paper and wondered if it is really true because I'm struggling to prove it:

> For any random variable $Y$ and value $a \in \mathbb{R}$ we have: $$\mathbb{E}[Y] \leq a + \int_a^\infty \mathbb{P}(Y \geq t)dt$$

I tried expanding $\mathbb{E}$, but so far no luck. Maybe there is just a special case in which it holds, but I didn't find anything on Google. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Works for nonnegative $Y$ using $E(Y) = \int_0^\infty P(Y\ge t) dt$.

Comment: Use integration by parts on the definition of expected value.